# Expose getter function in nested Dto with class-transformer | Nest js

Tags: typescript, nestjs, dto, class-transformer

I want to Expose a getter function in a nested DTO class. But then when I try to create that DTO class and supply it with an object, an error comes up said: that getter function is required in the object that I supplied. By adding the Expose decorator to the getter function, we no need to set that getter function when creating the DTO class right? Since it's also not a setter. But why typescript said we need to set the value of that getter function?

Here is my DTO

```
export class ResponseDto {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    power: number;

    @Exclude()
    createdAt: Date;
    
    @Type(() => SkillDto)
    skill?: SkillDto;

    constructor(partial: Partial<ResponseDto>) {
      Object.assign(this, partial);
    }
}

class SkillDto {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    power: number;
    @Exclude()
    cooldown: number;
    duration: number;

    @Expose({ name: 'tier'})
    get tier() {
        return this.power + this.cooldown + this.duration;
    }    
    constructor(partial: Partial<SkillDto>) {
      Object.assign(this, partial);
    }
}
```

`const response = new ResponseDto(data);`

Got error when creating the ResponseDto class variable. It said 'tier' property is missing in SkillDto. I don't want to set the initial value of the 'tier' property since its a getter function.